# How to download multiple images without save dialogue box(Default functionality always prompt multiple save dialogue for each Image)

Tags: javascript, jquery, download

I tried different solutions to download multiple images at one click

My 
Html code

```
<div>
  <button type="button" class="photo" onclick="SaveAllImages()" style=" float: right; height: 30px; width: 120px;">Save Images</button>
</div>
```

Script

```
function SaveAllImages() {

  $('.Image').each(function (index, item) {
    if (this.src != undefined) {
      index++;
      var imagename = "CarePlanPage" + index + ".jpg";
      var a = document.createElement('a');
      a.href = this.src;
      a.download = imagename;
      document.body.appendChild(a);
      a.click();
      document.body.removeChild(a);
    }
  });
  return false;

}
```

It downloads records correctly but if I changed Chrome setting

> Settings>Advanced Setting >Download

and check or uncheck "ask where to check each file" Checkbox it again Show save as dialogue,I don't want save dialogue box at any how because I don't know image count so it will mess up with multiple save dialogue box,

Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Actually, js has restrictions to work with local file system, and you cannot do this action. To load many files at one time you can use archive, but this solution requires server side, that will be generate zip archive with images.

Comment: Thanks @SergeyShvager but it is also Ok if you can help me to create Folder and save images in Folder but I am not able to create folder also.If I will Create One folder and save images then it will also a good solution prob is i need to use client side scripts

Comment: I found out, that there is library that can generate folder, put there files from client side and generate zip from this folder. You can check this out: [JSZip](http://stuk.github.io/jszip/)

Comment: Thanks @SergeyShvager  Zip is a good Idea.but it's a zip file,can we create folder instead of zip to solve issue if possible.:-)

Comment: I'm sorry, because of file system's restrictions, I can propose only generating zip file.

Comment: I appreciate Your solution,I am working on this...Thanks

Comment: super helpful, thanks @SergeyShvager - consider making it an answer!